# Git subtree -- sharing subtrees with contributors

Tags: git, git-subtree

In some of the repositories that I'm working with, I found git subtree does not behave as expected when sharing repos.

Here's the scenario:

1. I own main repo X and push it to origin.
2. My colleague pulls repo X from origin, adds a subtree pointing to another repo Y, makes the commit, and pushes X back to origin.
3. I pull X and see the changes my colleague has made. However, in my local repo, the folder containing subtree Y is just another file. I can't pull changes from repo Y even after adding repo Y as a remote. Git subtree always says that the folder already exists whenever I do a `git subtree add` and says that it can not find the commit when I do `git subtree merge`.

Does anyone know the best way to deal with this situation? Ideally I would like to also be able to pull changes from repo Y even though I am not the user adding repo Y as a subtree of repo X. Is this possible? If not, what is the best way to share repositories having subtrees?

Comment: normally when your collegue adds the repo Y as a subtree, all files and folder should be present inside the folder containing subtree Y

Comment: for a tutorial on how to use git-subtree, you can checkout this page: http://psionides.eu/2010/02/04/sharing-code-between-projects-with-git-subtree/

Comment: Yes, the files are there. The problem is when I want to sync the change from repo Y *myself*, I can't do it. I have added repo Y as a remote in my local repo X, but it does not work. Subtree add says this is not possible since the files are indeed already there. Subtree merge says there is a missing commit.

Comment: normally when you do a git clone from the X remote repository you wouldn't have to change anything; just add the remote... if you say you wan to sync, you mean pull and merge?

Comment: Yes. I want to also fetch and merge from repo Y into repo X, still maintaining repo Y as a subtree of X. I know the remote URL, I know that it is a subtree of repo X, but I don't know how to also fetch and merge changes from repo Y.

Comment: normally these commands should do the trick: git fetch sub (or git fetch --all)
git subtree merge -P subdir -m "merged changes of sub" sub/master. If not; please post your exact error message.

Comment: oh by the way; did your collegue import the subtree with or without the squash command? You need to do the same: see notes in the link I provided.

Comment: also: do a check of your git history; you should see commits from both repo X and Y. If your collegue used squash you should see at least one "squashed" commit from repo Y

Comment: @bow It can be useful if you post the exact commands with which you are trying with `git subtree merge`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `git subtree pull`.

`git subtree add` adds a history of another repository as a *new* subtree -- in your case, this has been done by your colleague, so it won't work

`git subtree merge` merges the changes up to a given *local* commit into the subtree -- as you have not pulled those changes yet, it won't work either

`git subtree pull` pulls the changes from another repo and then merges them into the subtree. Tested with the following command sequence (uses the 'master' branch of the subtree repository, adjust if needed).

```
~ $ mkdir subrepo
~ $ cd subrepo
~/subrepo $ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in ~/subrepo/.git/
~/subrepo $ touch file
~/subrepo $ git add file
[master (root-commit) 03a9f75] file added
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 file
~/subrepo $ cd ..
~ $ mkdir repo1
~ $ cd repo1
~/repo1 $ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in ~/repo1/.git/
~/repo1 $ git commit --allow-empty -m "initial commit"
[master (root-commit) ec7e1c5] initial commit
~/repo1 $ git subtree add --prefix=sub ../subrepo master
git fetch ../subrepo master
warning: no common commits
remote: Counting objects: 3, done.
remote: Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (3/3), done.
From ../subrepo
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Added dir 'sub'
~/repo1 $ cd ..
~ $ git clone repo1 repo2
~ $ cd subrepo
~/subrepo $ echo 'new version' > file
~/subrepo $ git add file
~/subrepo $ git commit -m "file changed"
[master c72ac6e] file changed
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
~/subrepo $ cd ../repo2
~/repo2 $ git subtree pull --prefix=sub ../subrepo master
remote: Counting objects: 5, done.
remote: Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (3/3), done.
From ../subrepo
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
 sub/file | 1 +
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
~/repo2 $ cat sub/file
new version
```

Comment: Hmm..this is weird :/. In the problematic repository that I'm working on, I have an error saying `fatal: entry  not found in tree {commit_hash}`. I then did a `git show {commit_hash}` and could see the commit (it's the subrepo commit).

Comment: Wait, I figured out what's wrong. `pull` does indeed work finally, and the problem is an extra slash `/` in the prefix argument that I'm using. I did not expect `--prefix` to be sensitive to this, but apparently it does. Anyway, thanks for pointing me to the right direction :).

Answer (score 1):

Normally these commands should fulfill all your needs; unless you messed things up underway. Note issues with Squash on this [site](https://mackuba.eu/2010/02/04/sharing-code-between-projects-with-git-subtree/)

add a repository as subtree in another

```
cd super
git remote add sub git@gitlab:chris.maes/sub.git
git fetch sub #or use: git fetch --all
git subtree add -P subdir -m "add sub as subtree in subdir" sub/master
```

merge changes in subproject into superproject

```
git fetch sub (or git fetch --all)
git subtree merge -P subdir -m "merged changes of sub" sub/master
```

push changes made in superproject to subproject

```
git subtree split -P subdir -b backport
git push sub backport:master
```

Comment: This works for pushing changes from repo X to the remote repo Y (which is quite well documented). My problem is *I can not pull changes from repo Y into my local repo X* because it is my colleague who added repo Y as a subtree of X instead of me. When I do `subtree add`, `git subtree` refuses to do so saying that directory for Y already exists (because my colleague already added it).

Comment: that's because you don't need to do git subtree add anymore, just git subtree merge...

Comment: http://psionides.eu/2010/02/04/sharing-code-between-projects-with-git-subtree/ is a deadlink.

Comment: I have corrected the link. Thanks for notifying.